# Linked List of Intervals

Tags: c++, c, algorithm

I have the following two questions.

1. I'm aware of the concept of a linked
   list. What is a linked list of
   intervals?
2. I need to store a very huge (more than 100 bits) number in C/C++ and perform bitwise operations on it. Without using any big number library, what would be the best data structure to handle this scenario ?

Thank You

Comment: "linked list of intervals" Where did you come across this?

Answer (score 4):

1. The name doesn't ring any bells. If intervals are objects, then it's just a linked list that stores those objects. Perhaps you mean a [skip list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skip_list)?
2. If you're using C++, use a [bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/). Otherwise, I would just use a classic table of four 32 bit ints.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can a bitset store 100,000 bits ?

Comment: @James - it would depend on hardware too of course, but I would say yes, definitely. That's well under a megabyte of memory.

Comment: as much as I hate to suggest it, if the number of bits isn't known in advance, `std::vector<bool>` might actually be appropriate to use.

Comment: @jalf: noway, vector<bool> having an actual use? Heresy.

Comment: @DeadMG: yeah, I know. If it was me, I'd probably prefer to use `boost::dynamic_bitset` instead, but I guess since they're not deprecating `vector<bool>` in C++0x, I can't really object if people choose to use it as a dynamic bitset

Answer (score 0):

For the second part of the question, try [std::bitset](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/bitset/)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write your own class to handle large bit numbers (I don't know why you would), you could wrap a vector. You'd have to catch your own overflow though. This is a huge pain, and I only bring it up because this was a final project for us for a C++ class I took, lol. I don't recommended this =P

Answer (score 0):

I made a comment on this is another question, which was asked by someone else. This *seems* to be referring to my comment, so I'll explain what I meant. What I was suggesting was:

```
struct interval_node {
      int index;
      struct interval_node* next;
}
```

where index stores all the points where the bit "flips". This is a huge memory advantage if you have something like `11111111111100000000000`, because it only needs to store the fact that the first bit is 1 (outside of the struct somewhere), as well as that the bit flips in the 12th index (being 0-based), rather than storing each individual bit itself. This can scale to 100,000 bits without eating up as much memory as long as the sequence doesn't have a ton of things like

```
1010101010101010101010101010101010101010101010
```

Because the it flips at every bit.